# Finitely presentated subgroups of a group are normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If a group is finitely generated, then it is a quotient of the free group on the set of generators. Further if a subgroup of a group has some finite presentation, does it mean that it is normal, intuitively a presentation corresponds to idenitifying certain element (or words), so it might be in some sense a quotient, and therefore normal. Is this right?

Comment: Note that the group table for a finite group is a finite presentation (or can easily be made into one, depending on the form of presentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Every finite group has a finite presentation, but not every subgroup of every finite group is normal. For instance, the subgroup $\langle (1,2)\rangle$ of the symmetric group $S_3$ is not normal, but has the finite presentation $\langle x\mid x^2\rangle$.